# Setup Spring-Boot Maven Project

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, maven-3, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to configure Spring-Boot project from Spring Initilizr .
Dependencies --> **kafka,web**

When i imported this project i got error in pom.xml at line

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

as

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.mobicule.kafkaexample:Spring-Producer:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Cannot 
 access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-
 starter-parent:pom:2.0.6.RELEASE has not been downloaded from it before. and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mobicule.kafkaexample</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring-Producer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Spring-Producer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Under Preferences i have 
Installations as Embedded checked. Will this cause any problem ?
Also do i need to do maven installation in eclipse separately for this project to run ?

Please guide me , because i am not able understand any of the maven errors

Comment: I just successfully build a project using your POM file with `$ mvn clean package`

Comment: Hi Boris , you did this using terminal or Eclipse IDE ?

Comment: Both, a terminal and Apache NetBeans IDE (Clean and Build option).

Comment: Ok , so there is some problem in my eclipse . Do i need to install maven plugin ? is it compulsory ?

Comment: So you can build the project using the terminal?

Comment: Actually i don't know how to install and setup maven using terminal , so i am doing it with eclipse

Comment: completely clean your  local cache  $ dependency:purge-local-repository clean install

Comment: @AjinkyaKarode If you use Ubuntu, for example, you can install maven by typing: `sudo apt install maven`

Comment: Boris , thnx it worked i ran it once but when i tried to run it once again i got  another issue using  mvn -X spring-boot:run  i get error as tomcat port is already in use . i did   ps aux | grep tomcat   , but cant find any tomcat process running .  How do i stop spring-boot maven projects ??

Answer (score 0):

You are in offline mode.
See the exception

> access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-
>    starter-parent:pom:2.0.6.RELEASE has not been downloaded from it before.

What IDE do you use?

Edit: In Eclipse go to: Window/Preferences/Maven -> First checkbox sets Maven into offline mode. Check if this is selected. If selected -> unselect and try to build again (clean install)

Comment: Hi , i use ECLIPSE neon IDE

Comment: I got what you are saying , i am in offline mode so maven is not able to download jars externally . But when i checked my .m2 folder there is no settings.xml to change <offline>true</offline> to false . There is only repository folder

Comment: I edited the answer so you can see how to turn maven "online" again.